# Disable the parent event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a problem in javascript.

this is my html

```
<td onclick="a();" >
     <input type="text" onclick="b();" value="" />
</td>
```

when I click the input text, I want b function only to be executed. But, now a is also executed. How do I stop a function be getting executed?

I tried with the following but no success

```
 $j("input").click(function(event){
     event.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$j("input")` or `$("input")` ?

Comment: make sure the jQuery click handler is in a dom ready handler

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/mrpg4/1/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xBfPf/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may work

```
  <input type="text" onclick="b();event.stopPropagation();" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats that `j` after `$`

try

```
$("input").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
return false; 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

inline `js` code no need of `jQuery`.

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/XsB4b/)</kbd>

```
 <input type="text" onclick="b();
       window.event.cancelBubble = true;
       window.event.stopPropagation();" value="" />
```

---

[event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.stopPropagation?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.stopPropagation)

[`window.event.cancelBubble`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.cancelBubble)`= true;` for IE

---

or with jQuery

wrap your code in [DOM Ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/XsB4b/1)</kbd>

```
$(function () {
    $("input").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
function a(){
    console.log('a');   
}

function b(){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log('b');   
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4QKJ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this 
in **HTML**

```
<td  >
     <input type="text" value="" />
</td>
```

In JS

```
$("td").on("click",function(event){
 event.stopPropagation();
if(event.target=="input")
{
 b();
}
else{
a();
}
});
```